# Where to Place Div Without Ruining Current Layout

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using a couple divs to style my background as well as style an overlay for hovering. The problem is that I'd like to create an additional div so that I can style a box on hover as well, but I'm not sure where to place the new div in the HTML without it screwing up my formatting (class .captionbox for example).

My code and JS Fiddle is below. Any help is appreciated.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxmkuqxh/)

```css
body {
        background: url('http://www.bootply.com/assets/example/bg_blueplane.jpg');
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .bg {
        position:fixed;
        width:50%;
        height:50%
    }
    #nw {
        background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
    #ne {
        top:0;
        left:50%;
        background-image: url('news1.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
    #sw {
        top:50%;
        left:0;
        background-image: url('drinks1.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
    #se {
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
    .overlay {
        height:100%;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
        -moz-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
        -o-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
        -ms-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
        transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
    }
    .bg:hover .overlay {
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
        opacity: 1;
        height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-weight:100;
        color:white;
        font-size:36pt;
        white-space:nowrap;
        -webkit-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
        -moz-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
        -o-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
        transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
    }
    .bg:hover .caption {
        color:#7D7D7D;
        font-size:72px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        margin-right:70%;
    }
    .captionbox {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:white;
        opacity:0;
        border: 5px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div id='nw' class='bg'>
    <div class='overlay'>
         <span class='caption'>Night Life</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='ne' class='bg'>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>News</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='sw' class='bg'>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Food & Drink</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='se' class='bg'>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Events</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you like to simplify your markup? [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/joraw/1/edit).

Comment: Yes, I'm going to compare your code to mine. I'm building a site for the sake of learning CSS so I definitely am going to need to learn to consolidate like this. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, in my example each section div is floated to the left. Because they each take up 50% width and height, each div gets 1/4 of the viewports size. `html,body { height: 100%; }` allows each div to have its percentage height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the div `display:none` it won't take up any space on the page.  I presume as a caption box it's going to be `position: absolute`, so once that style is applied it won't affect your layout anyway. So you should be able to put it at the top level as a child of `<body>`.

Comment: That did work, so I appreciate your help. However, it pushed my text down that was in the box. How can I avoid that from happening?

Comment: Can you update the fiddle to show the issue? Hard to picture what's happening.

Comment: You're doing `background-position: absolute`, which is invalid.  Use `position: absolute`.